# Python Groupby Separate Filter for Each Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Say I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id':  [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3],
 'date': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
 'product': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to keep all data for each ID the day of and after they bought product 'b' and get rid of all data before they bought product 'b'. ID 1 would have no data because they did not purchase the product, ID 2 would have data for the 3rd and 4th day, and ID 3 would have data for days 1-4.

I know that I could groupby id and then filter rows from individual groups but I can't figure out how to make the filter dynamic based on the group. I've tried looping through the groups but it's slow (right now I have 19,000 IDs but it'll only grow as I continue the project).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your expected output? It would help visualize a great deal. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the products "b" with `eq` and set the successive rows to True per group using `groupby`+`cummax`. Then slice the dataframe

```
df[df['product'].eq('b').groupby(df['id']).cummax()]
```

output:

```
    id  date product
2    3     1       b
3    3     2       a
4    3     2       b
6    2     3       b
8    2     3       b
9    3     3       c
10   2     4       c
11   3     4       c
```

*NB. this assumes the dataframe is ordered by date. If not use `sort_values(by='date')` (or `by=['group', 'date']`)*

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me understand why cummax() returns all successive rows? If I read the above from left to right it seems as though the successive rows would already be gone/filterd out from the eq().

Comment: `cummax` will transform all the `False` that follow a `True` into `True`, thus keeping the rows